# pass the argument of array from command line instead of scanner in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I write the code in Java to get the arguments by scanner. I have several classes : ChartToHtml.java, ExecutionProperties.java, ExecutionV2.java, TestCase.java, TestCaseList.java, Section.java and all of them will be called from ImplTest.java.

They are working fine when I execute either from eclipse or command line by scanner. The problem is when I want to execute them via program arguments and pass the arguments in one single line. It considers the input as single `String` but I have to use a `String[]` as input for Section class.

Here are my Section class and ImplTest classes

```
public class Section {
     Ini.Section root;
     ArrayList<String> StringList = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<TestCase> TCList = new ArrayList<TestCase>();
     String sectionSearched;
     String section;
     String filenameSearched;

     public Section (){

     }

     public Section (String filenameSearched, String sectionSearched) {
         this.sectionSearched = sectionSearched;
         this.filenameSearched = filenameSearched;
     }

      public ArrayList<String> findSection(String filename, String... wanted) throws IOException, IOException {
             Ini myIni = new Ini(new File (filename));
            for (String d : wanted) {
                root = myIni.get(d);

                    for (String name : root.keySet()){
                        StringList.add(root.get(name));
                    }
              }
              return StringList;
      }     

      public ArrayList<TestCase> convertStringToTestCase(ArrayList<String>StringList){
          for ( int i = 0; i < StringList.size(); i++) {
              String name = StringList.get(i) ;
              TestCase tc = new TestCase (name);
              TCList.add(tc);
          }
          return TCList;
      }
      public String[] getSection(int NumOfSec){
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          while (true) {
              System.out.println("Input section name:");
              section = scanner.nextLine();
              for (int i =0; i<NumOfSec; i++){
                  String token[]= section.split(" ");
                  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(token));
                    return token;
              }

          }
      }     
}
```

My Main class

```
public class ImplTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ConfigurationException, TemplateException {
    ExecutionV2 ex = new ExecutionV2();
    TestCaseList tc = new TestCaseList();
    Section s = new Section();
    ChartToHtml chr= new ChartToHtml();
    ExecutionProperties ep = new ExecutionProperties();
    ImplTest imp = new ImplTest();

    String filename = ex.getcfg();
    String []sec = ex.getSection();
    int it = ex.getIterationMax();
    String runTCpath =ex.getRunTCdir();
    String dir = chr.getChartDir();

    ArrayList<TestCase> TClist = s.convertStringToTestCase(s.findSection(filename, sec));
    ex.executeTestCaseList(TClist, it , runTCpath);
    ex.getTCAttribute(TClist);

    ep.setConfigProperties(tc.getTCPassed(), tc.getTCFailed());
    chr.generateHistoryTable();
    chr.generateChartAndTableTemplate(tc.getTCPassed(), tc.getTCFailed(),ex.getNameList(), ex.getPassedList().toString(), ex.getItList().toString(),dir);
    }
}
```

Then I modified the main class to pass the arguments via run configuration and pass this single line:

```
ArrayList<TestCase> TClist = s.convertStringToTestCase(s.findSection(**args[0]**, **args[1]**));
    ex.executeTestCaseList(TClist, Integer.parseInt(**args[2]**) ,  **args[3]**);
    ex.getTCAttribute(TClist);

    ep.setConfigProperties(tc.getTCPassed(), tc.getTCFailed());
    chr.generateHistoryTable();
    chr.generateChartAndTableTemplate(tc.getTCPassed(), tc.getTCFailed(),ex.getNameList(), ex.getPassedList().toString(), ex.getItList().toString(), **args[4]**);
```

and pass this singe line into program arguments

`C:\\Users\\syuniyar\\.EasyTest\\4\\ccl\\config\\test2.cfg 12346 5 C:\\EasyTest\\4\\bin\\runTC.exe C:\\Users\\syuniyar\\EclipseWS\Test3\\chart.html`

it is working fine. However, when I modify the input from `...12346...` to `...12346 12345...`, I get such error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "5": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I also try with VM arguments but the option of System.getProperty() is only for single string.
I know why I get this error because it reads 12345 as 'it' which is not correct. What I wanna ask :

Is it possible to have an array as single argument in main method?

Comment: Pass your arguments in quotes, seperated by a comma or whitespace or whatever you want (e.g `"12345 12346 6666 333"`). Then in your main method split the string with your seperator. You'll get an array.

Comment: I am not understanding the question exactly, but if you want to provide multiple strings to your class, you need to enclose them in double quotes, and you must do this for each argument: `program "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"... "argn"`.

Comment: The arguments you pass in `C:\Users\syuniyar\.EasyTest\4\ccl\config\test2.cfg`,  `12346`, `5`, `C:\EasyTest\4\bin\runTC.exe`, `C:\Users\syuniyar\EclipseWS\Test3\chart.html` are coming in as an array, one argument per value in the array.  I would print out the arguments you have with `System.out.println` (and a for-loop) to make sure you know what arguments are coming in where.  I think you'll solve your own problem.

Comment: sidenote: other users are trying to help to get your post into shape so it won't attract downvotes and/or close votes. I find it not polite if you keep undoing the edits from other users.

Comment: How do you want to run the program? From within Eclipse using program arguments, or completely from command line? If from command line: Can you show the full command including the program? Thanks.

Comment: @Ismail, it's working. I put quote and split the args, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, "Is it possible to have an array as [a] single argument in [a] main method?", no. The main method accepts arguments in the form of one array of String objects (usually called "args"). Each of these strings is considered an argument.

When executing the main method from the command line, these arguments come after the program name and are delimited by spaces. They are loaded into an array and passed into the main method.

As mentioned in the comments (esp. @Ismail Kuruca), if it is important to you to pass in several strings as one argument, you can concatenate the strings to make your arguments technically one String, and thereby treated as one argument.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I figure it out from Ismail Kuruca